# How can I show specific data un my Django form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm a begginner at Django and I'm making an app for lending books and now I'm trying to make a Form using these models:

In my app Books

```
Class CopyB(models.Model):
     Copy= models.Autofield(primary key=True)
     Condition= models.Charfield(max_lenght=20)
     IdBook=models.ForeignKey(Book, blank= false, null= false ,on_delete= models.CASCADE)
```

Also in my app Users

```
Class User(models.Model):
      Myid= models.Charfield(primary_key=True, max_length=20)
      Name= models.Charfield(max_length=20)
      Lastname= models.Charfield(max_length=20)
```

And in my app loans

```
From apps.books.models import CopyB
From apps.users.models import User

Class loan(models.Model):
      IdLoan= models.Autofield(primary_key=True)
      IdB= models.ForeignKey(CopyB,blank=False, null=False)
      IdU= models.ForeignKey(User,blank=False, null=False)
```

What I want to do is making a Form from the model loan and on that form on the field IdB I only want to show in the select input just Books in the model CopyB that in the field Condition is equal to available

But I don't know how to make it!
Thanks in advance

Comment: take a look at forms.ModelForm

Comment: Please don't ask questions like "can you code this for me, because I don't know how to do it". Show us what you've tried. Show us a form that does more or less what you wants and explain what you're trying to achieve and what the form doesn't do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to filter the objects that meet the condition that you want and fill out the choice field with those.

```
class LoanForm(forms.ModelForm):

  IdB= forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=CopyB.objects.filter(condition='available'))

  class Meta:
    model = Loan
    fields = "__all__"
```

OR

```
class LoanForm(forms.ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model = Loan
    fields = "__all__"

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    super(LoanForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['IdB'].queryset = CopyB.objects.filter(condition='available')
```